# Mixed content error message in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, http, https, mixed-content

I have installed SSL in my hosting provider and tested it on whynopadlock.com/ , and it keeps saying my site is not fully secure:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite.nl/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://mysite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/bg-01-free-img.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Now when I look into media files in Wp, the link says https and not http. I have been looking for hours now and the plugins SSL Insecure Content Fixer and Really Simpel SSL havent been working either.

Any ideas to how to solve this would be appreciated!

Comment: If paste `https://mysite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/bg-01-free-img.jpg` into your browser address bar and open it there, what happens? Does it show the padlock or does it instead redirect you to  `http://mysite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/bg-01-free-img.jpg`? (non-https)

Comment: @sideshowbarker it shows the padlock

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this plugin for your website it will fix everything related to mix content and show your website secure with green signal.

Plugin name
Easy HTTPS Redirection
By Tips and Tricks HQ

Anyother help needed ? let me know.
Thank you

Comment: i activated that plugin but still getting the same message :(

Comment: enable force redirection by clicking at checkbox

Comment: select all the optionns through checkbox , could you send me screenshot please?

Comment: kindly share your website url as i can further review it , you have configured the plugin correctly  , this plugin makes all the unsecured content to secure https..

Comment: www.vrieselaarfinance.nl

Comment: Hello kindly reupload this image or re embed this image http://vrieselaarfinance.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/bg-01-free-img.jpg

Comment: I already reuploaded that bro, same message where can I re embed it?